# Java to download files from s3 to ec2 via internal communication

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

1. Hi, I'm trying to fetch files from AWS s3 to ec2 to zip it, and then wanna upload the zip back to s3, 
   all via AWS internal communication.
2. In order to achieve this, I have set up VPC, and both s3 and ec2 are in the same region.
3. I'm able to fetch files from s3 to ec2 on AWS CLI but don't know how to achieve the same using java.

   - I need help for this purpose

Comment: If your instance is in public subnet in a vpc, your traffic also goes thorough the internet. Does not matter if you use cli or not. Aws has Sdk for [Java](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/).

Comment: Have seen that but i'm not sure whether it fetches the file through public or private network

Comment: Its up to you. How did you design your vpc? Is your instance in a private subnet? Do you have S3 gateway setup for the vpc?

Comment: yes. And instance can work on public and privte both

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean my ec2 instance can communicate to s3 publicly and privately both

Comment: Then you are done. Just use the SDK and that's it. S3 gateway takes precedence over NAT gateway, so your S3 communication will be private.